# Which planet does Leia represent in the New Republic?

Tags: star-wars, princess-leia, star-wars-bloodline

In the book *Star Wars: Bloodline*, Princess Leia is a senator in the New Republic.

All senators that I am aware of in canon represent a planet. For example, Senator Casterfo is from and represents the planet Riosa.

My question is, **given the destruction of Alderaan, which planet does Leia represent at the New Republic Senate?**

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Pablo Hidalgo answered this [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/788048578988027904); according to him, she represents the Alderaan *sector*, rather than the planet:

[image]

> **@BartlamTyler:** I've nearly finished reading bloodline a I still don't know what planet or sector Leia represents if any
>
> **@pablohidalgo:** Same as when she was in the Imperial senate: the Alderaan sector.

It seems like a misconception<sup>1</sup> that Senators exclusively represent planets; [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/820051108705931264), Pablo Hidalgo notes that senators can represent either planets or sectors, based on such factors as population, among others:

[image]

> **@thesupremepablo** Do senators represent sectors or systems? Trandosha and Kashyyyk are in the same sector and each have a senator.
>
> **@pablohidalgo** Depends on population and other factors. Amidala and Palpatine before her represented the Chommell sector.

This, of course, leads to the question<sup>2</sup> of precisely *who* she was representing; there are several (not mutually exclusive) possibilities:

- There were other inhabited worlds in the sector, and Leia represents them<sup>3</sup>. Although none are specifically identified in the new Canon, we know it isn't impossible; both Eriadu and Seswenna - respectively the homeworlds of Grand Moff Tarkin and [Admiral Motti](https://www.starwars.com/databank/admiral-motti) - are to be found in the Greater Seswenna sector
- Her position is symbolic, granted in recognition of her service in the Rebellion and her role in toppling the Empire
- She governs the Alderaanian people in exile. We know that more than a few Alderaanian citizens survived the planet's destruction; [one of them](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Nash_Windrider) is an Imperial officer in the canon novel *Lost Stars*, and we meet several in the Marvel [*Princess Leia* comic series](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Princess_Leia).

  This theory is given extra credence by the canon novel *Life Debt*, which features a chapter set in the "Alderaan Flotilla", a coalition of ships parked in the planet's former location and housing members of the Alderaan [diaspora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaspora)<sup>4</sup>:

  > Out there waits an infinite black space horizon of Alderaan, now reduced to rock.
  >
  > The flotilla is safe, at least. Seven ships belong to the flotilla, now, including the Alderaanian frigate Sunspire. Another gift from the nascent Republic. Or, rather, another gift from their princess.
  >
  > The ships float near to one another, gathering in a circle and protected by the deflector shield to keep out both the asteroids and, hopefully, marauders.
  >
  > *[...]*
  >
  > "This is our home. This patch of sky is ours. Our world was here. And the diaspora has returned us to this place.
  >
  > <sup>*Aftermath: Life Debt* Interlude: "The Alderaan Flotilla"</sup>

  This interlude ends with the Alderaanian government (such as it is) deciding to use the remains of the Death Star to build a more permanent space station home; though whether or not they did remains unclear.

---

<sup>1</sup> Or a retcon, more likely

<sup>2</sup> Posed by DaaaahWhoosh in comments

<sup>3</sup> And I'm sure they're just pleased as punch that their only government representative isn't native to their world

<sup>4</sup> Thanks to BBlake for pointing this out in comments

Comment: So I guess the next question would be, does anyone actually *live* in the Alderaan sector?

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh A good question. Even if not, it's possible that she represents the Alderaani people-in-exile, and they call her "Senator of Alderaan" as a short-hand. It's also possible they just gave her the position in recognition of her service in the Rebellion

Comment: Does sector == solar system? Or is a Sector a wider swathe of space than a solar system?

Comment: @TylerH Normally no, a sector is larger than a system and may comprise multiple inhabited planets. The Seswenna sector, for instance, contained both Eriadu and the planet Seswenna. We don't know of any other inhabited worlds in the Alderaan sector (in Canon), but that doesn't mean there aren't any

Comment: I see, thanks. Although, a Solar System includes multiple planets, too.

Comment: @TylerH: Not necessarily.

Comment: One of the new canon books (I believe it was Aftermath: Life Debt) actually states that many of the survivors of Alderaan have returned to the system and are living aboard a makeshift space station they are building there built out of parts from their ships, pieces of the planet debris, and the remnants of the second Death Star.

Comment: @BBlake You're right; I haven't read *Aftermath* yet, so I had to go out and check. I've added that in; thanks

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh I'd say, even if we knew of no other planets in the Alderaan sector, the passage included in the answer already acknowledges the Alderaan flotilla is floating where Alderaan used to be. So the people on those ships, at the very least, are living in the Alderaan sector.

Comment: @vapcguy that quote was not included when I wrote my comment, thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Answer (score 8):

She represented the Area Alderaan used to be in.

> Twenty-three years after the Battle of Jakku, Organa was a senator in the Galactic Senate of the New Republic on Hosnian Prime.[11] As she did in the Imperial senate, she represented the Alderaan sector in the Galactic Senate.

from Wookieepedia

Comment: reading that literally it seems humorous to think of her representing a bunch of pulverized rocks...

Comment: @Michael if [trees can have a speaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lorax) then surely rocks can too.