# Why was Naboo important enough to have a seat in the Senate?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

[There were on the order of 1000 senators](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/85316/11841) in the senate. It seems the [Star Wars galaxy was incredibly vast](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/76421/11841) with millions of systems.

In light of this, it seems a bit strange that Naboo would have a seat on the senate. As best I can tell the world is fairly nondescript and inconsequential from the content shown/discussed in the movies.

The senate was a relatively small representation of the overall galaxy - why was Naboo important enough to get a seat on the senate?

Either canon/legends answers are fine.

Comment: Naboo was important because of its extensive spice moons and plasma core.

Comment: In real world, the importance of a nation is not always related to its population. For example, Vatican has a tiny population but the voice of his leader is heard almost anywhere in the world.

Comment: @Taladris sure, but if there was a representation of Earth that included 2 world leaders would the Vatican (or any of the numerous smaller countries) be chosen?

Comment: IIRC the senator was the representative of the sector. A non-descript planet could achieve a senatorial role simply by being the most important planet in that region of space. Exceptions being made for the most important planets of course (think Core worlds having multiple senatorial planets per sector).

Comment: The description on wookieepedia mentions that Naboo also represents the *backwater* planets of the Chommell sector. Evidently Naboo is the most civilised and prosperous planet in the vicinity.

Comment: It probably helps you getting representation in the Senate if you have an undercover Sith Lord manipulating things.

Comment: Palpatine almost certainly spent decades manipulating things to enhance Naboo's importance, too. Step 1, achieve representation. Step 2, become Senator. Step 3, become Chancellor. Step 4... destroy Republic.

Comment: @WiggotheWookie sith lord + plot devices ==> guaranteed representatives.

Comment: Because of the importance of Jar Jar Binks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### It isn't

As [I've mentioned](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/146758/31051) on the site before, it's not necessarily true that a senator represents a single system. Palpatine and Padmé actually represent the Chommell sector, a somewhat larger region of space (though how much larger is unknown). Pablo Hidalgo confirmed this [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/820051108705931264) in January 2017:

[image]

> **@thesupremepablo** Do senators represent sectors or systems? Trandosha and Kashyyyk are in the same sector and each have a senator.
>
> **@pablohidalgo** Depends on population and other factors. Amidala and Palpatine before her represented the Chommell sector.

Why both (known) senators of that sector have come from Naboo is a question that has thus far not been answered; some possibilities include:

- Naboo is the only sovereign system in the sector
- Naboo is the *largest* sovereign system in the sector
- Blind chance

Comment: Ahem; http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Janus_Greejatus/Legends

Comment: Also ahem; http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Naboo_Senatorial_Delegation

Comment: @Valorum Hey, don't blame me that they keep retconning this nonsense. Padme's [Databank article](http://www.starwars.com/databank/padme-amidala) also calls her the Senator of Naboo, which leads me to believe that "Naboo" is a convenient shorthand for "Chommell", probably to the consternation of any other planets in the sector

Comment: Makes little sense that there isn't a military ready to break a blockade on their capital world

Comment: @Andrey Not even [every country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_without_armed_forces) on Earth has a standing army

Comment: Obviously Naboo "naboomanded" the voting districts to ensure that it maintains its grip on power.

Comment: Indeed.  The UN never refers to the council members by the city or building from which they operate their domestic government.

Comment: @can-ned - But many other organizations do. "The White House" did this. "Pyongyang" said that. "The Kremlin" did so-and-so.

Comment: @Adamant  Quite so.  I also do the same for things above my local administration — e.g. “Harrisburg is telling such–and–such to them–and–them.”  Seems more likely to be something used between peers or as a way to avoid implying more ownership or position than diplomatically necessary, wouldn't you say?

Comment: Is it pertinent that Naboo was described as a “sovereign system” when Amidala was introduced during that one scene in Phantom Menace?  Maybe not every one of those ‘millions’ of systems could be so described.  Of course, your answer goes towards explaining exactly _why_ Naboo would be considered sovereign in its region of the galaxy.

Comment: FWIW, calling "Chommell sector" "Naboo" would be an example of "metonymy", and more specifically "synecdoche". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy